# Google Apps Sheet API: Can I write to a public spreadsheet without authenticating a user?

Tags: javascript, authorization, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to [write a list row](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=pt-BR#adding_a_list_row) to a public 'Published to the Web" Google spreadsheet from a Javascript app. I'm basically using the spreadsheet as a quick database that is open to anyone, but I can't seem to get the POST request to work.

```
curl -H "Authorization: <Client ID>" --data '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"><gsx:id>1</gsx:id><gsx:status>1</gsx:status><gsx:user_email>1</gsx:user_email><gsx:url domain>1</gsx:url domain><gsx:highlighted_text>1</gsx:highlighted_text><gsx:complete_text comments>1</gsx:complete_text comments><gsx:created_date>1</gsx:created_date><gsx:updated_date>1</gsx:updated_date><gsx:created_by>1</gsx:created_by><gsx:updated_by>1</gsx:updated_by></entry>' https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/asd2HIe_RkXHXbnszQwXV8NYSwsRC_Q9mUVZYFiWX99Q/1/public/full
```

The POST request above returns with a "Page not found" error, but the GET request to the same sheet works just fine. So I think the issue is with my authorization header.

I'd like to avoid having a user go through Google's authentication screen since it doesn't matter who writes to the spreadsheet.

Can I write without specifying a user?
What would the authorization header look like?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.